# Zeppelin execute job (all paragraphs) with parameters via REST API

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I have a zeppelin note that has many paragraphs. I have one paragraph that should receive/set up some parameters that will be further used by the other paragraphs.

I would like to submit a job via zeppelin REST API that will with these parameters set up in the body.

I know that in zeppelin there is a REST API service that runs a paragraph with
parameters in the body, example of such a call is

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{ "params": { "filename": "/myfolder/my_file.txt","min":0.89,"max":25} }' http://zep_host:zep_port/api/notebook/job/noteid/pargarph_id

I would like to have something similar for running the job (all paragraphs) with the parameters, without having to separated calls for doing this (one post call to the paragraph that sets up the parameters, and one call to submit the entire job).

I look forward for your solutions.

Thanks.

Florin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no facility to use the input JSON for processing in 0.7, I tracked the entire execution flow of Rest API source for both Synchronous and Async submissions, they just take the input JSON and not use it. The only input taken ahead for processing is your notebook & paragraph IDs. Below is first few code lines of Zeppelin's paragraph run function.

```
  /**
   * Run a single paragraph.
   *
   * @param paragraphId ID of paragraph
   */
  public void run(String paragraphId) {
    Paragraph p = getParagraph(paragraphId);
    p.setListener(jobListenerFactory.getParagraphJobListener(this));
    if (p.isBlankParagraph()) {
      logger.info("skip to run blank paragraph. {}", p.getId());
      p.setStatus(Job.Status.FINISHED);
      return;
    }
```

Obviously there are unlimited possibilities of processing for inputs which simply can not be provided out of the box. Each individual can expect different process to be executed based on their input so it is highly different to make a generic control flow inside Zeppelin.

Having said that, as a solution I had modified the source to serve my purpose in a slightly different way. If you also must use Zeppelin v0.7, modifying the source to make data flow as you want is the only way possible in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Zeppelin has vairous APIs which can use ZeppelinContext for different interpreters.

Go through : https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/usage/dynamic_form/intro.html#creates-programmatically-scope-note

Code:

```
val date = z.input("date")
println("Sitaaaa : " +date);
```

Prints date sent as output

Comment: Assuming I use z.noteTextbox, how do I pass the parameters during a REST API call? The 0.8.0 documentation seems to mention only about passing params when running a single paragraph